# Futures and Promises in Erlang

Tags: concurrency, erlang, promise, future

Does Erlang has equivalents for [Future and Promises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)? Or since future and promises are solving a problem that doesn't exist in Erlang systems (synchronisation orchestrating for example), and hence we don't need them in Erlang.

If I want the semantics of futures and promises in Erlang, they could be emulated via Erlang processes/actors?

Comment: Erlang's concurrency model is different. Erlang's basic building block for concurrency systems is its lightweight processes (which are much lighter than operating system processes). See http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/conc_prog.html for example on how to "hook on completion".

Comment: That said, https://github.com/gleber/erlfu .

Comment: I think if you are looking for a future in Erlang you may be trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 8):

You could easily implement a future in Erlang like this:

```
F = fun() -> fancy_function() end,

% fancy code

Pid = self(),
Other = spawn(fun() -> X = F(), Pid ! {future, self(), X} end).

% more fancy code

Value = receive {future, Other, Val} -> Val end.
```

Having this functionality in a module and building chains from it should be easy too, but to be honest I never actually missed something like this. You are more flexible if you just freely send messages around.

Comment: You need to add a reference to the message and match it in the reply. Otherwise, you could confuse one reply for another.

Answer (score 5):

The RPC module contains the `rpc:async_call/4` function that does what you need. It will run a computation anywhere in a cluster (including on `node()`, the local node), and allow to have the result waited on with `rpc:yield/1`:

```
1> MaxTime = rpc:async_call(node(), timer, sleep, [30000]).
<0.48.0>
2> lists:sort([a,c,b]).
[a,b,c]
3> rpc:yield(MaxTime).
... [long wait] ...
ok
```

You can also poll in non-blocking ways by using `rpc:nb_yield/1`, or for a limited number of milliseconds with `rpc:nb_yield/2`:

```
4> Key2 = rpc:async_call(node(), timer, sleep, [30000]).
<0.52.0>
5> rpc:nb_yield(Key2).
timeout
6> rpc:nb_yield(Key2).
timeout
7> rpc:nb_yield(Key2).
timeout
8> rpc:nb_yield(Key2, 1000).
timeout
9> rpc:nb_yield(Key2, 100000).
... [long wait] ...
{value,ok}
```

That's all in the standard library and ready to be used.

Comment: A disadvantage of this approach is that is does not allow for anonymous functions, i.e. you can't do `rpc:async_call(node(), fun() -> timer:sleep(30000) end)`.

Comment: It is possible by using `erlang:apply/2` as the function provided to `rpc:async_call/4`. You can do something like `rpc:async_call(node(), erlang, apply, [fun() -> ok end, []]).`.