# Does Erlang support an "ask" operation?

Tags: erlang, promise, akka, actor

In Akka you got two different sending mechanisms: `!` for *telling* the actor stuff, and `?` for *asking* an actor about stuff, the main difference for those unfamiliar is that `actor ! message` is a *fire-and-forget* operation, and `actor ? message` returns a promise of a result that then at a later time needs to be resolved.

I haven't been able to find anything regarding this in Erlang as googling "Erlang ask operation" or simply "Erlang ask" yields less-than helpful results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it does not, but what you request is easy to implement:

```
ask(Pid, M) ->
  Promise = erlang:monitor(process, Pid),
  Pid ! {ask, Promise, M},
  Promise.
```

Awaiting the result of the promise can now be done by:

```
force(Promise, Timeout) ->
  receive
    {result, Promise, R} ->
      erlang:demonitor(Promise, [flush]),
      {ok, R};
    {'DOWN', Promise, process, _, Reason} ->
      {error, {callee_died, Reason}}
  after Timeout -> {error, timeout}
  end.
```

If you don't want to do anything in between asking and the force, then you can use the OTP behavior `gen_server` which has a `gen_server:call/3` essentially implementing these two functions in one go.

Note how in the above we request a monitor reference on the target `Pid` which allows us to monitor it if it dies. We also use this reference as a unique tag for the promise so we can find it among other messages that looks like it in the mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

Erlang doesn't support promises nor futures. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635890/futures-and-promises-in-erlang) for other examples of simulating them. Also see [this article](http://erlware.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/brief-overview-of-concurrency.html) for explanation why Erlang uses Message Passing instead of Promises and Futures.

Comment: Akka uses message passing along with promises, they aren't mutually exclusive concepts

Comment: I didn't say they are :-) Supporting promises would be at the expense of fault tolerance, so Erlang explicitly chose message-passing as the only concurrency model. See Joe Armstrong's PHD thesis where he explains his reasoning behind implementing Erlang the way he did (2.4.3 on page 22): http://ftp.nsysu.edu.tw/FreeBSD/ports/distfiles/erlang/armstrong_thesis_2003.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The `?` in Akka is built using `!`. What it does is: It creates a new temporary actor which is used as the `sender` for a message being dispatched using ordinary `!`. If it does not receive anything in time, it sets the promise to failed. If it does it fulfuls the promise.

The asked actor will then reply to that temporary actor (which is how you know to which message was actually replied, otherwise you would have to keep track of that yourself in a map or something similar).

This is why you have to import the `ask` pattern explicitly and why it is called a pattern, not a built in primitive like `!` is.

You could implement the same pattern in Erlang.